# Default value to a optional class variable parameter function call in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function-calls, class-variables

I am trying to pass a class variable as an optional parameter to a function. But it requires a default value. What could I set the default value for the optional class variable.

```
Private Function SaveFruit(Optional byval tempBanana As BananaClass = ?)
```

Comment: set it to Nothing

Comment: the function variable accepts nothing..thanks

Comment: If you want the value to be optional, then what is the value you want it to have if there's none passed?

Comment: If there is a banana class then I would make a different changes in database and add to a separate table with a if clause otherwise I am gonna do other calculations. Depending upon the function call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reference types'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) default value is [`Nothing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx) (the `null` reference).

```
Private Function SaveFruit(Optional byval tempBanana As BananaClass = Nothing)
    If tempBanana Is Nothing Then tempBanana = OtherDefaultBanana
    .....
End Function
```

As shown in the example above you have to check if it's `Nothing` with the [`Is`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) before you can use it, otherwise you will get a `NullReferenceException`. Then you can either assign another instance which already exists or one that you initialize now.